# place a marker on leaflet map from mongodb coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, leaflet

I would like to place markers on a leaflet map but from a database,
I would like to save on mongodb the lat and long and show 'em like markers on my map, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create a request for example with JQuery Ajax:

```
$.ajax({url: "/your_data_provider.php", success: function(result){
     //result = JSON.parse(result); // If your result is not a json Object.
     // It depends on what your data looks like

     //Example 1: Lat and Lng has a own field in the db
     result.forEach(function(data){
         var lat = data.lat;
         var lng = data.lng;
         var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
     });



     //Example 2: you have one geojson-data string field "geo" in db
     // Before inserting in db create a featuregroup `var fg = L.featureGroup();`
     // and add all markers to the group `marker.addto(fg);`.
     // Then you can call `var datageo = fg.toGeoJSON();` and add this datageo to the db in the field "geo"
     result.forEach(function(data){
         var geo = data.geo;
         L.geoJSON(geo).addTo(map);
     });
     //https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/


  },
   error: function(xhr){
      alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }});

});
```

Also you need a data provider. You can create a REST-Api `www.url.com/data/postions/` or calling directly for example a php file.

php file:

```
// I have never used MongoDB, you have to code your own request. I copied it.

<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

try {

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    $listdatabases = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listDatabases" => 1]);
    $res = $mng->executeCommand("admin", $listdatabases);

    $databases = current($res->toArray());

    $result = new array();
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($databases->databases as $el) {
         $result[$x]['id'] = $el->id;

         //Example 1:
         $result[$x]['lat'] = $el->lat;
         $result[$x]['lng'] = $el->lng;

         //Example 2:
         $result[$x]['geo'] = $el->geo;

         $x++;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
    $error = new array();
    $error['exception'] = $e->getMessage();
    $error['line'] = $e->getLine();

    echo json_encode($error);
}

?>
```